# dcef3 child process doesn't quit

Tags: delphi, c++builder-xe, chromium-embedded

I'm trying dcef3 to make a simple browser which opens a fixed url. I've set CefSingleProcess as false. As soon as I run the application, two processes of the same name are created (watching in the process explorer). Quit the application, and only one of the processes goes, other remains.
The OnProcessMessageReceived call never gets called. The OnRenderProcessTerminated call never gets called.
Is there anything specific I need to do to get cef to kill it's child processes? Any pointers would be helpful.
Thanks!

Comment: Did you call CefShutdown? What version of CEF?

Comment: Using dcef3 as a component in C++ builder so there's no place to call CefInitialize or CefShutdown. However, problem is now solved! Had been banging head at keyboard since yesterday and it was trivial. Had not called CefLoadLibDefault() after setting CefSingleProcess as false. Will post full answer to my question as soon as I'm allowed to do so :)

Comment: @Avnir, I have met a similar CEF issue(though it's in MFC not Delphi), so I'm curious of the full answer.
I've tried to upvote you over 15 reputation, so when you have time to share more details. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:
In the application, I was doing this:

```
CefSingleProcess = false;
Application->Initialize();
Application->MainFormOnTaskBar = true;
Application->CreateForm(__classid(TForm2), &Form2);
Application->Run();
```

I had skipped a call to CefLoadLibDefault(). To fix it, I did this.

```
CefSingleProcess = false;
if( !CefLoadLibDefault())
        return 0;
Application->Initialize();
Application->MainFormOnTaskBar = true;
Application->CreateForm(__classid(TForm2), &Form2);
Application->Run();
```

All working fine now. @pac, hope you find this useful.